# How to install Ubuntu on a blank hard drive?

Tags: 14.04

Do I have to install the drivers for my computer in order to install this OS?

My hard drive has no OS on it.

Comment: No, Ubuntu comes with its own drivers and doesn't require any other operating system. Just install Ubuntu and it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Download the Ubuntu ditsro you like.
Than use [UNetbootin](https://unetbootin.github.io/) to create a bootable USB flash drive.
(Or you could burn a DVD from the iso)

You can use the USB flash drive to install and even try Ubuntu first.

There is no need for any other OS on your computer.